# How does Truffle know the address of contracts published via truffle migrate?

Tags: truffle, testrpc, truffle-migration

In Truffle's documentation, it says `DeployedAddresses.sol` is how Truffle identifies and stores the addresses of contracts published to the blockchain via `truffle migrate`.

How does this file work, and what does it look like? If I publish an `Adoption` contract, how does Truffle know that the word `Adoption` in `truffle console` refers to that contract?

Answer (score 6):

Good qus. As far as I know. Truffle will store your contract address in **build/contacts/[CONTRACT.json]** file

Truffle will map contract address under network json object with index.

```
 "networks": {
    "1": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0x77685437e762aaa90d4b6924aa9445c1198013f1"
    }
  },
  "schemaVersion": "1.0.1",
  "updatedAt": "2018-02-16T10:49:18.298Z"
}
```

If you delete json file, It will create new json file with new contract id.

When you run migrate/console, truffle will refer your [CONTRACT.json] file with corresponding network and address.

Comment: How is the network number generated? e.g. You've shown "1" above. But on my local machine network number is "1532795656486" - which seems random.

Comment: The network number is read from the connected rpc client / blockchain. If you look into your ganache UI you see the network number which is set in the JSON in the top bar of the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Truffle requires you to define Migrations by creating a deployer for the Adoptions contract.

For example `migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js`

```
var Adoption = artifacts.require("Adoption");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Adoption);
};
```

Building the contract with `truffle build` also creates an JSON file `build/contracts/Adoption.json` which contains all required metadata.

*DeployedAddresses.sol* is **created on runtime** by truffle when you run tests.

See also: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/471#issuecomment-315166855

Comment: I knew all this going into asking this question. None of this answered my question unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you need be more specific. ^^
You may also ask truffle support. E.g via Gitter http://truffleframework.com/support